# Sabr Calibration not fitting the market volatility

Tags: calibration, sabr

I am trying to calibrate SABR but I do not fit the given volatility.

```
   import QuantLib as ql
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import  differential_evolution
moneyness=np.array([    120.00, 115.00, 114.00,     113.00,     112.00,     111.00 ,
     110.00, 109.00 ,108.00,    107.00, 106.00, 105.00, 104.00, 103.00, 102.50, 102.00,
    101.50, 101.00, 100.50, 100.00,     99.50,  99.00,  98.50,  98.00,  97.50,  97.00,
    96.50,  96.00,  95.50,95.00,    94.50,  94.00,  93.50,  93.00,  92.00,  91.00,90.00 ])
moneyness=moneyness/100
fwd = 1.361794
strikes=fwd*moneyness
expiryTime = 30/365
marketVols = np.array([0.0302,  0.08827,    0.10019,    0.11206,    0.12343,    0.13305,    0.13968,
              0.14325,  0.14431,    0.14337,    0.14077,    0.13706,    0.1325, 0.12664,
              0.12355,  0.12024,    0.11694,    0.11371,    0.11062,    0.10772,    0.10526,
              0.10307,  0.10118 ,0.09953,   0.09811,    0.0967, 0.09487,    0.09313,    0.09096,
              0.08795,  0.08359,    0.07751,    0.07003,    0.06203,    0.04591,    0.02975,    0.01347 ])
marketVols=1-marketVols
marketVols[20]=1-10.97/100

def f(params):
    params[0] = max(params[0], 1e-8)  # Avoid alpha going negative
    params[1] = max(params[1], 1e-8)  # Avoid beta going negative
    params[2] = max(params[2], 1e-8)  # Avoid nu going negative
    params[3] = max(params[3], -0.999)  # Avoid rhp going < -1.0
    params[3] = min(params[3], 0.999)  # Avoid rho going > 1.0

    vols = np.array([
        ql.sabrVolatility(strike, fwd, expiryTime, params[0],params[1],params[2],params[3])
        #(Rate strike, Rate forward,  Time expiryTime,Real alpha,Real beta,Real nu,Real rho,

        for strike in strikes
    ])
    return ((vols - np.array(marketVols))**2 ).mean() **.5

bounds = [(0.000001,1000000),(0.000001,0.99) ,(0.00001, 1000000), (-0.99, 0.99)]
result = differential_evolution(f, bounds,tol=0.0000001)

params=result.x

print(1-ql.sabrVolatility(1.279, fwd, expiryTime, params[0],params[1],params[2],params[3]))
newVols = [ql.sabrVolatility(strike, fwd, expiryTime, params[0],params[1],params[2],params[3]) for strike in strikes]
plt.plot(strikes, marketVols, marker='o', label="market")
plt.plot(strikes, newVols, marker='o', label="SABR")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well, it looks pretty good to me.
The SABR model has only 4 parameters and there is only so much you can do with them.

If you have a lot of volatilities, especially if they have a quite irregular distribution, like in the picture, this is what you can expect when trying to fit the SABR model.